# Calculation of Relay current

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, electrical

I am using Relay OJE series SPST and I want to drive the relay with V=5v and the resistance through the coil is 125 ohm. From microcontroller 3.3v and 1k resistor. The NPN type is BC817-25 and the max hfe/B is 400.

What is Ib, Ic? And how much current goes through the coil? To make sure my relay type is ok and can handle the current!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BJT can't pull its collector below ground.

Instead it will go into saturation mode with \$V_{ce}\$ in the neighborhood of 0.2 V. So the voltage across the relay coil will be around 4.8 V. And the coil current will be about 40 mA.

If you buy a 5 V relay, this will be exactly what it expects and it will work accordingly.

Comment: It's common knowledge that many relays are designed so that they are guaranteed to become active at about 70% of their specified voltage. And that their \$\frac{R}{L}\$ is designed near their maximum guaranteed momentary frequency of operation. If you can find their latching time and their resistance, for example, you can work out the inductance, close enough.

Answer (score 1):

When the transistor switch is on (fully saturated), max. current will flow through the relay and the collector circuit which is \$\approx 5/125 = 40mA\$. You just have to make sure if it's within the current limits of the relay and the transistor,  going through the data sheet.